# Mapquest AppKey not working

Tags: javascript, mapquest

I am using Mapquest javascript Maps API for displaying optimized route.
I am getting error when page is loading

I http://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v7.2.s/mqa.toolkit.js?key= Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
Uncaught ReferenceError: MQA is not defined

My code was working fine but suddenly it's stopped working.
I have registered again for new appkey but same problem.

When I am using  http://open.mapquestapi.com  only map is displaying,but route is not displaying (addOptimizedRoute function used for route)
I have tried v7.2.s to v7.0.s but no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free & Open AppKeys work with the [MapQuest Free & Open APIs & SDKs](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open).
i.e., you're hitting the endpoint for the Enterprise Edition of the services, so your key won't work with anything hosted on www.mapquestapi.com.  There were licensing changes [announced late last year](http://devblog.mapquest.com/2014/11/17/are-you-a-community-edition-licensed-data-user/).

You'll want to use the OSM/Open Data version of the JavaScript Maps API, located here: http://open.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v7.2.s/mqa.toolkit.js?key=YOUR-KEY-GOES-HERE

Comment: Thank you. I have tried http://open.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v7.2.s/mqa.toolkit.js?key=<myappkey>. But not getting route in this postcodes (10011,10012,10013)    using "addRoute" function. But few other postcodes like(80201,80205,80216) are working fine. Is there any limitation of postcodes for Open API ? I have already checked following link for my problem- http://developer.mapquest.com/web/tools/getting-started/platform/licensed-vs-open ,                                                       but not getting my answer.

Comment: the Free & Open services utilize Open Data, which comes primarily from the OpenStreetMap community. This is different from the Enterprise Edition service, which uses data from a commercial vendor.